# Keeping two arrays, String[] and int[], parallel with merge sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I'm having trouble with keeping two arrays in parallel within my Merge Sorting algorithm.
Suppose I have array defMergeSort and intMergeSort2.

I would like to lexicographically order String defMergeSort,

```
String[] defMergeSort = {"Echo", "Alpha", "Charlie", "Beta", "Alpha", "Echo"};
```

Array intMergeSort2 represents the element position in parallel to defMergeSort. (Ex: defMergeSort[0] = Echo contingent to intMergeSort2[0] = 0, defMergeSort[3] = Beta contingent to intMergeSort2[3] = 3)
intMergeSort2 is to be rearranged in parallel to defMergeSort, although not numerically sorted,

```
int[] intMergeSort2 = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

The end result should look similar to this (Not sure if parallel ordering for intMergeSort2[] in my example is correct for duplicate Strings in defMergeSort[]):

- defMergeSort[0] Alpha =   intMergeSort2[1] 1
- defMergeSort[1] Alpha =   intMergeSort2[4] 4
- defMergeSort[2] Beta =    intMergeSort2[3] 3
- defMergeSort[3] Charlie = intMergeSort2[2] 2
- defMergeSort[4] Echo =    intMergeSort2[0] 0
- defMergeSort[5] Echo =    intMergeSort2[5] 5

The following merge sort algorithm can lexicographically order defMergeSort, although I cannot figure out how to keep defMergeSort in parallel as stipulated above:

```
//mergeSort code found at:
//http://www.buildingjavaprograms.com/code-files/2ed/ch13/MergeSort.java
public static void mergeSort(String[] defMergeSort, int[] intMergeSort2) {
    if (defMergeSort.length > 1) {
        // split array into two halves
        String[] left = leftHalf(defMergeSort);
        String[] right = rightHalf(defMergeSort);
        // recursively sort the two halves
        mergeSort(left, intMergeSort2);
        mergeSort(right, intMergeSort2);
        // merge the sorted halves into a sorted whole
        merge(defMergeSort, intMergeSort2, left, right);
    }
}

// Returns the first half of the given array.
public static String[] leftHalf(String[] defMergeSort) {
    int size1 = defMergeSort.length / 2;
    String[] left = new String[size1];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        left[i] = defMergeSort[i];
    }
    return left;
}

// Returns the second half of the given array.
public static String[] rightHalf(String[] defMergeSort) {
    int size1 = defMergeSort.length / 2;
    int size2 = defMergeSort.length - size1;
    String[] right = new String[size2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        right[i] = defMergeSort[i + size1];
    }
    return right;
}

// Merges the given left and right arrays into the given
// result array.  Second, working version.
// pre : result is empty; left/right are sorted
// post: result contains result of merging sorted lists;
public static void merge(String[] defMergeSort, int[] intMergeSort2,
String[] left, String[] right){
    int i1 = 0;   // index into left array
    int i2 = 0;   // index into right array
    for(int i = 0; i < defMergeSort.length; i++){
        if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length &&
        left[i1].compareTo(right[i2]) <= 0)) {
            defMergeSort[i] = left[i1];
            i1++;
        } else {
            defMergeSort[i] = right[i2];
            i2++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just sort one array, and use the same indexes to change the values of the other one. but it doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: Just use a `List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>>`.  That way you have an ordered list of String->Integer key/value pairs.  Then sort away.

Comment: Thanks, Tripp Kinetics. I haven't learned about List<Map.Entry<String,Integer>> yet so I will look into it.

Comment: @TrippKinetics Yeah, that would work. Essentially it's using an `Entry` to do what the `DataElement` does in my answer. It's a lot less clear what the code is doing and falls down for linking more than 2 objects though so I'd still recommend creating a class for this unless the collection is really temporary.

Comment: @TimB You'd have to be careful to implement `compareTo()`, `equals()` and stuff like that with a custom class, wouldn't you?

Comment: @TrippKinetics In most cases I'd expect the sort to be done using a custom `Comparator` so `compareTo` and `Equals` become irrelevant. Yes if you were needed a natural sort you would need to implement `Comparable`. However considering `Entry` doesn't implement `Comparable` you would need to do that anyway. It's a good point though, I'll add a note to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Define an object containing your integer and string values, have a single array of that object, sort that array.

i.e.

```
class DataElement {
    final String str;
    final int i;

    //Add constructor here
}

DataElement[] array; // sort this array
```

Note that you will either need to implement `Comparable` in the DataElement or specify a `Comparator` to the sort method in order to control the sorting.

Comment: Awesome Tim B, why didn't I think about doing that? Thanks.

Comment: @user3657529 Get used to thinking in terms of objects and grouping things like that will become automatic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Tim B's answer is probably the best approach, I would just like to mention that since  the class is just an int and a string, you can use the predefined datastructure std::pair. Just have an array of these pairs and sort by the string. To do this you can use std::sort() defined in , if I'm not wrong std::sort is a MergeSort. You can override the compare function defined with your own.

I find it extremely convenient to use pair in such situations as yours. Make sure you include .

Look into http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/ for reference.

Look into http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ for reference.